# Whenever I upload an .md file to GitHub there are random texts between the code

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

[These random texts  appear after uploading file to git hub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neUDN.jpg)

I used `jupyter nbconvert my_notebook.ipynb --to markdown` this command to convert jupyter notebook to an (**MD**) file so I can show it on github. when i open the md file everything is good but when i upload the file to my repository using VSS some random texts appear. how to get rid of it Thanks

Comment: Your table output has custom header/styles, and `nbconvert` doesn't know how to deal with those. github shows notebook file just fine (including table/dataframe display because they're self-contained HTML).

Comment: By the way, you can point [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/) at a notebook on GitHub and view it that way. No need for conversion. You can share the URL with non-coders and they can view it nicely. You can see several examples on the main nbviewer page and if you examine the URLs you can start to see the pattern for the URL relative GitHub's site  GitHub's rendering is best considered a quick-preview. nbviewer is superior for viewing notebooks than the GitHub render in several ways. nbviewer is provided by the Jupyter community for viewing and sharing notebooks hosted anywhere on the web.